# swfupload check if flash installed

Tags: javascript, flash, swfupload

I am using swfupload and wanted to notify the user that they need flash installed for this to work.

I found this: http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/2140 although have no idea where I need to implement this.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var upload0, upload1, upload2, upload3, upload4, upload5;
window.onload = function () {


    upload{$smarty.section.r.index} = new SWFUpload({
            // Backend settings
            upload_url: "{$REQUEST_URL}{if $swfcallbackid}/id/{$swfcallbackid}{/if}?swfcb={$row.formname}&{php}echo session_name();{/php}={php}echo session_id();{/php}",
            file_post_name: "{$row.formname}",
            post_params: {"{php}echo session_name();{/php}" : "{php}echo session_id();{/php}"},             
            // Flash file settings

            file_size_limit : "500MB",
            file_types : "{$row.mask|default:"*"}", // valid file type mask                                     
            file_types_description : "{$row.mask_desc|default:"All Files"}",

            file_upload_limit : "0",
            file_queue_limit : "1",

            // Event handler settings
            //swfupload_loaded_handler : swfUploadLoaded,               
            file_dialog_start_handler: fileDialogStart,
            file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
            file_queue_error_handler : fileQueueError,
            file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,

            //upload_start_handler : uploadStart,   // I could do some client/JavaScript validation here, but I don't need to.
            upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
            upload_error_handler : uploadError,
            upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
            upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,

            // Button Settings
            button_image_url : "{$HOME}/webapp/shared/swfupload/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.jpg",
            button_placeholder_id : "{$row.formname}_button",
            button_width: 63,
            button_height: 23,
            button_window_mode: "TRANSPARENT",

            // Flash Settings
            flash_url : "/webapp/shared/swfupload/Flash/swfupload.swf",

            custom_settings : {
                progressTarget : "{$row.formname}_progress",
                cancelButtonId : "{$row.formname}_cancel",
                filenameDisplayId : "{$row.formname}"
            },

            // Debug settings
            debug: false
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use swfObject to embed flash, that detects if the user has it or not and can install the plugin with leaving the page, its pretty much the industry standard

Comment: Ok so I have found this example: http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/swfobjectdemo/index.php on their website. But I am not sure which part of the JS I have to change. I sit just the part at the bottom?

Comment: Go to the project site for swfObject and learn how to embed from there, http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/